# Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null. Cannot figure it out

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. It seems to work fine in Firefox but I get the `uncaught type` error in Chrome. What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let url = `https://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/characters/?api_key=[apikey]`;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                getElements(response);
            }
        }

        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        request.send();
        alert(request.status);
        alert(request.statusText);
        var xml = request.responseXML;
        var table;

        var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("character");
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var user = users[i];
            var names = user.getElementsByTagName("name");
            var name= user.getElementsByTagName("real_name");
            for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
                alert(names[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = table;
    });
});
```

I can view the data in Firefox, however nothing is displayed in Chrome.

Comment: Please indicate which line is returning the error.

Comment: your code seems to expect both JSON result asynchronously, **and** XML response synchronously ... you can only get one type of response, and in your case, as you've indicated a mime type of text/xml, it will be XML only - and the result will be asynchronously available

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to get the response before it is given. I would use jQuery's ajax to complete the call.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/xml;"
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      alert(textStatus);
      var xml = data;
      var table;

      var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("character");
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];

        var names = user.getElementsByTagName("name");
        var name = user.getElementsByTagName("real_name")
        for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
          alert(names[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

        }

      }
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = table;
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      alert("error occured\n" data.message);
    }
  });
```